# Casting pointer from a framebuffer to another address

Tags: c, pointers, stm32

I have a framebuffer or a bitmap that is 16 bit

```
uint16_t framebuffer[320*240];
```

I assign a framebuffer address to it

```
  pLayerCfg.FBStartAdress = (uint16_t)&framebuffer;
```

`FBStartadress` is

```
uint32_t FBStartAdress;              /*!< Configures the color frame buffer address */
```

cast from pointer to integer of different size

I get the following error

Comment: What is the type of `pLayerCfg.FBStartAdress`? Shouldn't it be a pointer? Why are you casting an address to become a `uint16_t` instead of a pointer?

Comment: The framebuffer isn't "16 bit", the framebuffer is an array of 16-bit integers. A good solution would be to make `FBStartAdress` a pointer to `uint16_t`, i.e. the type should be`uint16_t *`. Then you could make it point to the first element of the `framebuffer` array and not need any casting.

Comment: `(uint16_t)&framebuffer;` tries to cast a *pointer* value (usually 32 or 64 bits wide) to a 16-bit integer...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can't change that, because it's a hardware accelerator and it should point to the address of the ```framebuffer```

Comment: @Lundin You are an embedded guy, that's STM32LTDC hardware layer, how would I configure it probably to point to at 16bit framebuffer ?

Comment: When you do `(uint16_t)&framebuffer` you cast the pointer to the type `uint16_t`. But the actual type of `FBStartAdress` ***isn't*** `uint16_t`. I'm guessing you're confused because the array itself is an array of `uint16_t`. That doesn't mean "pointers" to it should be that type as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so how it should be ?  ```(uint32_t)&framebuffer```

Comment: Yes, or better yet (with the types you're supposedly forced to use) `(uint32_t) framebuffer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are casting to the wrong type. If the `FBStartAdress` has type `uint32_t` then you should be casting to `uint32_t`:

```
pLayerCfg.FBStartAdress = (uint32_t)&framebuffer;
```

If the compiler still gives you trouble you can cast it through the integer of the appropriate type like this:

```
pLayerCfg.FBStartAdress = (uint32_t)(uintptr_t) &framebuffer;
```

Comment: It should be noted that there is a semantic difference between `&framebuffer` and `&framebuffer[0]` (which is what plain `framebuffer` will decay to). `&framebuffer` is a pointer to the whole array, and its type is (in this case) `uint16_t (*)[76800]`. `&framebuffer[0]` is a pointer to the first element, and its type is `uint16_t *`. What is typically wanted is a pointer to the first element only.